# What's the T[number] mean in typescript code?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

found the code first in http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#example-1

and then found this similar code in typescript codebase:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/cases/conformance/types/conditional/conditionalTypes1.ts#L75

```
type KnockoutObservable<T> = { object: T };
type KnockoutObservableArray<T> = { array: T };

type KnockedOut<T> = T extends any[] ? 
                       KnockoutObservableArray<T[number]> : 
                       KnockoutObservable<T>;

type KnockedOutObj<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: KnockedOut<T[P]>;
}
```

what is the T[number] mean in the code?

in the Typescript Handbook example, it said

> the element type of the array as T[number]

while test in the playground(just for testing), replace `T[number]` with `T` or `T[any]` seems no different, but can not replace with `T[string]`(why?).

the `[number]` after `T` seems not an index.

Answer (score 18):

`Array` is declared using an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures), something like this:

```
interface ArrayMaybe<Element> {
    [index: number]: Element;
}
```

(I call this `ArrayMaybe` because I haven’t specifically copied `Array`’s declaration, and it’s not relevant.)

Index signatures indicate that a type can have properties using any value of that type as the key or index, but with the same type of value at each such key/index. So `ArrayMaybe<number>` can have values at `0`, `1`, `42`, and so on, but wherever it has such properties, the property’s value will be a `number`.

Coming from the other side of things, when talking about some type `T`, `T[____]` references some particular property of `T`. So `{ foo: 'bar'; }['foo']` will refer to type `'bar'`. In the case of an index signature as we see above, we can use `T[number]` to refer to the type of that index signature—in the case of `ArrayMaybe`, that is `Element`. Which is precisely how it’s being used in your example.

You can’t use `T[string]` because `Array` doesn’t have a string index signature. You’re allowed to use those, but `Array` doesn’t. Since it doesn’t have a string index signature, `T[string]` isn’t legal. You can use `T['length']`, though, since `Array` does have a property with *that particularly string*. Using `string` or `number` refers to *any* string or number—which requires an index signature.

For an example of a string index signature, consider

```
interface Dictionary<Value> {
    [key: string]: Value;
}
```

With this, we *can* use `T[string]` when `T` is some `Dictionary`—and `T[string]` will be `Value`.

Comment: Is using `T[number]` equivalent to inferring the Array type like so? `type BoxedValue<T> = { value: T }; type BoxedArray<T> = { array: T[] }; type Boxed<T> = T extends (infer A)[] ? BoxedArray<A> : BoxedValue<T>;`

Comment: @wensveen In `Boxed`, if `T` is an array, then `T[number]` is equal to `A`. So you could write `type Boxed<T> = T extends any[] ? BoxedArray<T[number]> : BoxedValue<T>` and it would be the same. I think using `infer` is more readable here, though, and you can’t skip checking that `T` is an array first either way so `T[number]` can’t get you out of making a conditional type. On the other hand, if you were dealing with a situation where `T` is already an array type, `T[number]` _does_ get you out of a conditional type, which may be more readable, compile faster, and limit recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to find basic explanation here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

> When Flatten is given an array type, it uses an indexed access with number to fetch out string[]’s element type. Otherwise, it just returns the type it was given.

```
type Flatten<T> = T extends any[] ? T[number] : T;

// Extracts out the element type

type Str = Flatten<string[]>;
     
type Str = string

// Leaves the type alone.
type Num = Flatten<number>;
     
type Num = number
```

T[number] will return type of T array element

Answer (score 0):

Most likelly it's an indexed access with number to array regarding to [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html);

> When Flatten is given an array type, it uses an indexed access with number to fetch out string[]’s element type. Otherwise, it just returns the type it was given.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).